# Calling a function in respons to a wheel event in javascript, but only when the previous function call on the same event has finished

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

The wheel event, where `doStg` would do some animation, which has to finish, before doing anything else:

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', doStg, false)

let numb = 0

function doStg() {
    console.log(numb++)
}
```

### What I want to do:

Add `doStg` to the call stack only if the previous `doStg` has finished.

I could do something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', doStg, false)

let count = 0
let eventController = 0

function doStg() {
  if (eventController === 0) {
    console.log(count++)

    eventController++

    setTimeout(function() {
      eventController = 0
    }, 3000)
  } 
}
```

Now the function is only firing every 3 seconds. Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have global flag that is exiting function immediately if previous call didn't finish

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', doStg, false)
let isExecuting = false;
let numb = 0

function doStg() {
    if(isExecuting) return; // exit if there is already executing something

    isExecuting = true; // prevent next call
    console.log(numb++)
    // do something
    isExecuting = false; // enable for next
}
```